# Resize images on front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, resize

I used to resize the images on the back-end. But now, to decrease the overload of my server, I want to **resize the images on the front-end** and send by ajax the images reduced.

In this site I found an excellent js function that allow you to reduce they proportionally. It is:

```
function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
    return { width: srcWidth*ratio, height: srcHeight*ratio };
}
```

But I can't find how to couple it with my code.

The code that I have at the moment:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="formimages" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <strong> Upload image:</strong> <br></br>
    <input  type="file" id="file" name="file[]"  multiple>
    <button class="btn-primary" type="button" id="btn">Upload image</button>
</form>
<div id="preview">

</div>
<div id="response">

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#file').on("change", function () {
        //Clear preview
        $('#preview').html('');
        var images = document.getElementById('file').files;
        var browser = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        //Iterate the files:     
        for (x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
            var type = images[x].type;
            if (type != 'image/jpeg' && type != 'image/jpg' && type != 'image/png' && type != 'image/gif') {
                $("#preview").append("<p style='color: red'> The file isn't an image </p>");
            } 
            else {
                //Insert images into preview reducing the dimension:
                var object_url = browser.createObjectURL(images[x]);
                $("#preview").append("<img src=" + object_url + " width='250' height='250' style='width: 250px; height:auto; '><br><br>")
            }

        }
    });

    //Send the form:
    $('#btn').on("click", function () {
        var formData = new FormData($("#formimages")[0]);
        var route = "php/carga/adm_prodimages.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: route,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (info) {
                $("#response").html(info);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The code you have is only resizing the displayed dimensions of the image, it's not actually resizing the file. Resizing and saving a file is quite an involved task, and one that has been answered before. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes. I know that it's more complicated than only resize the preview. Thanks, in a while i'll see the question.